# Ruby RSpec/Capybara/Selenium not running javascript recently

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara

I am getting the following errors on my feature tests :

a) A test which exercises a javascript question modal no longer shows the modal:

```
  Failure/Error:
    accept_alert do
      click_link 'Delete'
    end

  Capybara::ModalNotFound:
    Unable to find modal dialog
```

b) A Rails `link_to` with `method: :post` failing to POST

```
RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/admin/users/29
```

Due to :

> Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET

-- https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

---

Gems:

```
  * capybara (3.33.0)
  * rails (6.0.3.1)
  * rspec (3.9.0)
  * rspec-rails (4.0.0)
  * selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
  * webdrivers (4.4.1)
```

on `ruby 2.7.1p83`

The problem is that the code has not changed, I can check out a commit from yesterday or last month of which it was working fine then, but at those commits now it fails. So what else can cause this?

I don't recall any system updates, there must be a way to debug this more and solve it?

Comment: It sounds like something was definitely updated, browser version perhaps?

Comment: Problem went away, I've not traced what caused/fixed it yet, but leaving this question open as others may find answers.